# How to configure jboss repository properly for my repository manager

Tags: maven, jboss, nexus

```
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
```

1. Which repository am I supposed to use?
2. I am unable to view the listing of any of the above repositories when I paste this URL on my browser?
3. What settings should I use to pull jboss release artifacts in Nexus?

Comment: This one works for me: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/

Comment: @Abe - Are you able to view the contents of the repository when you click on the above URL? I am unable to view any data

Comment: I am unable to view it in browser, however you could use the following link https://repository.jboss.org/nexus this link is mentioned in the gettting started link in below answer.

Comment: I am able to view the contents for other nexus repositories, but unable to view it for this one.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to add the JBoss repo - http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ in Nexus as a proxy type repo.
Secondly, include this one in the 'group' type repo.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following description:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users

and may be the simplest solution would be to use:

https://repository.jboss.org/

Comment: I was under the impression that everyone wanted to move away from https://repository.jboss.org/. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: JBoss is moving to Maven Central soon: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/09/8942/