# Maven Failing download the JBoss dependency

Tags: maven-2, jboss, m2eclipse

Below are my maven settings from behind the proxy

User Settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository>D:\path\mvn_repo</localRepository>
<pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
<proxies>
<proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <username>myusername</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <host>myproxyhost</host>
        <port>myproxyport</port>
    </proxy>

    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>myusername</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <host>myproxyhost</host>
        <port>myproxyport</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
<servers></servers>
<mirrors></mirrors>
<profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

Global Settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository>D:\path\mvn_repo</localRepository>
<pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
<proxies></proxies>
<servers></servers>
<mirrors></mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

However I get 'Connection timed out' when I try to execute test goal.
This happens with both maven command line and M2Eclipse. What more settings do I require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the proxy you are using requires NTLM authentication, which maven does not support. 
You can try to use CNTLM: 
http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

JBoss repository has been moved in June 2011 causing many other users to experience problems like you describe. Most likely you need to change the URL in your pom.

For more details, refer to

- [How to configure jboss repository properly for my repository manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144119/how-to-configure-jboss-repository-properly-for-my-repository-manager)
  and other answers listed as "Related" to above
- JBoss wiki for maven users: [Maven Getting Started - Users](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users)

PS. When doing the change, make sure to check all your poms that contain [repository blocks](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) because otherwise, broken JBoss URL may slip through these and kill your build