# where to get hibernate jars from?

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, jboss, pom.xml

i dont know how many of you noticed http://repository.jboss.org/maven2 is down. where are you getting your jars from now?

for example if you want hibernate 3.5.6-Final, where do you get it from?

thanks in advance

Comment: JBoss repo has been moved in June 2011 - did you check yesterday question and answers about this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657978/maven-failing-download-the-jboss-dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Hibernate's download page](http://www.hibernate.org/downloads), the JBoss Maven Repository is at https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

Your question is tagged with Maven-2, but if you're not using Maven to manage dependencies, you should be downloading the Hibernate Bundle from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.5.6-Final/).

Anyway, Maven can download them from the [Maven Central Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.5.6-Final/). You can use these dependencies for hibernate 3.5.6, with annotations, without specifying any additional repository :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

You might want to use the `hibernate-core` artifact instead, and other non-transitive dependencies you're intereseted in.

Take a look at this possible duplicate question: [How can I use Maven to get the latest Hibernate release?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1230249/851811)

By the way, it seems that repository.jboss.org/maven2 [is up](http://www.isup.me/http://repository.jboss.org/maven2).

Comment: hibernate-core is not there, if i download this one, will it be enough?

Comment: Are you using maven to manage dependencies? If you are, you can add the `hibernate-core` artifact with the same `<dependency>` in the answer, just changing `artifactId`. Maven will download the artifact from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.6-Final/) without need to add additional repositories. On the contrary, if you're **not** using maven to manage dependencies, you should be downloading the Hibernate Bundle from [SourceForge](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.6-Final/). I've updated the answer with this information.

Answer (score 1):

From Hibernate's site:
( http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore367FinalRelease )

I believe the URL of the repository should be 
http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ instead of http://repository.jboss.org/maven2